# How to iterate through axios interceptors and check if an intercepted is already added

Tags: javascript, axios, interceptor

How can I iterate through axios interceptors and check for a particular interceptor? For example, i want to check if a particular interceptor is (already) added?

I am aware of this code, but it is at the lower level, and not exposed (only `use` and `eject` are)

https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/core/InterceptorManager.js#L44

Comment: if you want to check for particular interceptor, you can add specific key to you object (request/response whr you used it). So you cam check for that key to know whichj interceptor is applied already

Comment: The only use case I could think of for this is if "foreign" code added interceptors to an axios instance, without your own codebase having this under control. Are you sure this is your use case? Because otherwise you're supposed to keep track of the interceptors you add yourself. It's kind of like setInterval, which returns an id or reference that you can use to remove/clear the thing you set before.

Comment: Thanks @Harish, sure, I can add to "MARK" it, but still, I am not aware of the mechanism of iterating through them to check if there is any MARKed :)